# Using Rx to cache result from webservice and use locally in C# UWP app

Tags: c#, caching, uwp, system.reactive

I have a UWP app where I call a web service to get a list of Products from the server.

**ItemWebService**

```
public async Task<IObservable<ProductListItem>> GetProductlistAsync()
{
     var productList = await _restClient.Get<IEnumerable<ProductListItem>>($"{_serviceUrl}/productlist");
     return productList.ToObservable();
}
```

**ProductListItem class**

```
public class ProductListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SkuValue{ get; set; }
}
```

I want cache the `productList` for a specific time period (for example let's say 10 mins). Whenever `GetProductlistAsync()` is called, it should look the cache 1st and return if cached list is present.

I tried keeping a local variable in the `ItemWebService` to cache the list. But whenever user navigates to another page, the variable gets cleared.

**Note : I will be calling this service from different pages of my UWP app. So the code should not clear cached variable when user navigates to another page.**

Following is the code I tried.

```
private IObservable<ProductListItem> cachedProductList;

if (cachedProductList == null)
{
   var dbProductList = await GetProductlistAsync();
   var period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
   var observable = Observable.Interval(period).Publish();
   observable.Connect();
   observable.Subscribe(async l =>
                           {
                               cachedProductList = await 
                               GetProductlistAsync().ToObservable().Replay();
                           }
                        );
}
```

I want to achieve this using `Rx Extensions`.

Comment: Why don't you just cache the call within `GetProductlistAsync`?

Comment: @Enigmativity How can I cache within the GetProductlistAsync? I cannot access Microsoft.extenstions caching within my UWP app

Comment: @RN92 - Just hang on to a copy of `productList` - as long as it is not stale just return that.

Comment: @Enigmativity How'd you do that in cache? Can you please write an answer for this?

Comment: @RN92 - Are you using a specific cache already?

Comment: @Enigmativity No, I just want to cache the result from API call to memory

Comment: @RN92 - across separate calls to the API? Where are the callers calling from?

Comment: @Enigmativity GetProductlistAsync() calls an API.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm trying to understand the lifetime of the data to see if you can just simply cache it using a field-level variable and a timer or you need something more sophisticated link caching to disk or something.

Comment: @Enigmativity I need to refresh my cache every hour

Comment: You seem to simply be avoiding answering my questions.

Comment: @Enigmativity I would prefer to have a field level variable and a timer which would refresh the cache every hour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189036/discussion-between-rn92-and-enigmativity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something as simple as this work?

```
private static IEnumerable<ProductListItem> _productList = null;
public async Task<IObservable<ProductListItem>> GetProductlistAsync()
{

    var productList = _productList;
    if (productList == null)
    {
        _productList = await _restClient.Get<IEnumerable<ProductListItem>>($"{_serviceUrl}/productlist");
        productList = _productList;
        Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromHours(1.0)).Subscribe(x => _productList = null);
    }
    return productList.ToObservable();
}
```

Comment: No this doesn't meet my expectations. As I have mentioned in my question, whenever user navigates to another page, the variable gets cleared. _productList is null again when user comes back to this page even after few seconds.

Comment: @RN92 - Which is why I asked you, "Yes, I understand that. I'm trying to understand the lifetime of the data to see if you can just simply cache it using a field-level variable and a timer or you need something more sophisticated link caching to disk or something." But you also told me "I would prefer to have a field level variable and a timer which would refresh the cache every hour." You need to clarify your question.

Comment: I really appreciate your interest in helping me getting through this. I would always prefer to have a simple solution, if it is not achievable via a simple solution you may suggest another way of doing this. My requirement is that I need to remain this cache even if user navigates to any other page, because this same service is accessed from different pages of the application. So if a user request from another page, the service should be able to serve the cached result. And the cache should also be  refreshed each hour. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not up with UWP so I'm not going to be able to help. I'd suggest you edit your question to get it back on the homepage.

Comment: I guess the cache should persist if we change the _productList to static variable.

Comment: @RN92 - Can you try it and let me know?

Comment: Worked !!. I'm gonna edit your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a `ServiceCollection` with dependency injection. You can have a look at this [sample application](https://github.com/Microsoft/InventorySample/blob/master/src/Inventory.App/Configuration/ServiceLocator.cs) by microsoft. This helped me in my case of holding a Service across the application once it is retrieved from api.

In which you have to use `AddSingleton` to return same object. `AddTransient` will return different objects. `AddScoped` will return based on the scope you are invoking.